# How can I copy gems to another server?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a server, "server1", set up with with Ruby 1.8.7 and Rubygems 1.6.2, with several gems installed.

I want to replicate it on another server "server2" which has matching versions of Ruby and Rubygems.
I FTP'ed the installed gem folders from server1 to server2 into the same paths.

Now, in server2 when I do:

```
gem list
```

no gems appear, although they were copied into the correct gem path.

Can anyone tell me whether this is a correct way to install gems, or whether there are better option rather than installing each gem on its own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do `gem env` on `server1` you should see a `GEM PATHS:` entry, followed by some directories. Those are what need to be duplicated.

Rubygems keeps track of the installed gems, but I don't remember exactly where. You should be able to get everything by doing the containing folders.

Comment: that is what I did. But then when I do gem list on server2 nothing is being displayed. Is there some refresh command maybe that I am missing? Thanks

Comment: Note the `gem list` is looking in the `specifications` folder for .gemspec files.

Comment: @Usering have you solved your issue? How?